# Unable to remove the row from table in which foreign key exists in MVC

Tags: linq-to-sql

In my mvc application I have 2 tables named:
    detail(srNo, ID, work), master(ID, name,plan) that are related with foreign key relation ship from detail to master using "ID" field.
 "ID" field  is primary key of master table.
"srNo" field is primary key of detail table.

From the "ID" field, this 2 tables are joined with foreign key relation ship.

Now the Problem is:
While adding any row to database, we are first make entry in master table , then in details table.
And sometimes due to some exception, when row is succesfully added in master table but can not add in detail table. Then I want to perform rollback from master table.

But when I want to delete the row with recently added ID value (grom linq to sql), which is added in master table it is giving me exception that forign key realtion ship is there .....

And at that time in detail table there is no row of that id field.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

it seams that data is inserted in child table also. first you have to delete from detail table using deleteallonsubmit(detail) and then from the master table. can you explain what is meant by exception, is it error or your validation

```
public ActionResult CreateRec(Master _Master, IEnumerable<Detail> Detaildata,FormCollection collection)
{
  MasterRepo _MasterRepo = new MasterRepo();
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (_detail != null)
            {
                foreach (var objdetail in DetailData)
                {
                    Detail _Detail = new Detail();
                    _Detail.FirstField = objdetail.FirstField;
                   _Detail.SecondField = objdetail.SecondtField;
                    _Master.Detail.Add(_Detail);
                }
            }
          _MasterRepo.Save();  
        }

}
```

Comment: No data is inserted in child table when I am going to delete from master table:

Comment: It is not giving any validation error, it is giving the error that can not delete where foreign key relation exist.

Comment: are you calling one submitchanges for child and parent or both are persisted to database separately

Comment: I have added my new answer as comment field capacity is less. Please see that answer. and help

Comment: please edit your answer while posting code press code button from formating so that it can be readable

Comment: it seams you are calling submitchanges twice you should call it once. then you don't need any roll back. if any error occur transaction will roll back

Comment: I can not call submitchanges once, without submitchange to master table, i am not able get the object of master table and then this object I will assign in the detail table field in which foreign key realtion ship exist.

Comment: See the above edite answer. it will give you some idea. I haven't tested this snippet but i used it and it should work in this way

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code

master objmaster= new master();
objmaster.id =count;
objmaster.name= name1;
..
  objEntities.AddObject("master", objmaster);
  objEntities.SaveChanges();
try
{
   detail objDetail = new detail()
    master objMaster = (from r in objEntities.master where r.Id == count select r).First();
    objDetail.master = objMaster;
     //  Suppose I get any (format, null pointer exception here)
     objDetail.folow = sfields[0];
     //In case of exception this below code will not be excecuted

objEntities.AddObject("detail", objDetail);
  objEntities.SaveChanges();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{

//Here i want to delete the row which I have added in master table:
   // I write the code for this
   master objMasters= (from r in objEntities.master where r.Id == count select r).ToList();
   objEntities.DeleteObject(objMasters);
   objEntities.SaveChanges();
}

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to submit both of them together so they are in the same transaction.  Then there is no need to write rollback code as the master won't get inserted if the detail fails.
Try this instead:

```
master objmaster= new master(); 
objmaster.id =count; 
objmaster.name= name1; 
.. 
objEntities.AddObject("master", objmaster); 
// == removed save changes call here ==
detail objDetail = new detail() 
// == no need to reselect master from the database, you already have it
// == so just assign it, and that will take care of the references/foreign-key
objDetail.master = objMaster; // Suppose I get any (format, null pointer exception here) 
objDetail.folow = sfields[0]; //In case of exception this below code will not be excecuted

objEntities.AddObject("detail", objDetail); 
// == save at the end ==
objEntities.SaveChanges();
```