# Saving runtime decided values to different tables in db

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have a view to create an "Instruction". I need to enter InstructionName, Description, and few Attributes to it. The number of attributes is determined at runtime. When "more attributes" is clicked I replicate a div which contains AttributeId(Dropdown) and AttributeValue(Textbox). The isntruction details are entered in Instruction table and the attribute details are entered in InstructionAttribute table. The definition for Create view is 
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

The model Document contains many properties along with InstructionName, InstructionDescription, InstnAttribId, and InstnAttribValue. How can I save these informations.

Thanks for any help in prior.

Answer (score 0):

Please see my following answer. It is for edit case but give you some idea
[Unable to remove the row from table in which foreign key exists in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838463/unable-to-remove-the-row-from-table-in-which-foreign-key-exists-in-mvc/3839121#3839121)
this is the case if you are using linq to sql. Tell me if you need more help